# How to create IServiceCollection from existing one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Let's say I have some kind of sub App that needs some services registered in the main App plus some specific services of its own. I want to know if there's a better/natural way for doing this (some extension method perhaps?). This is what I've done:

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(this IServiceCollection main)
{
    IServiceCollection sub = new ServiceCollection();
    foreach (var serv in main)
    {
        sub.Add(serv);
    }
    return sub;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ConfigureServices` method of `IWebHostBuilder` to inject service collection. And then that instance will be passed to `ConfigureServices` method of Startup class. And I think that extention method is the way to go. But, in my opinion renaming extension method to `AddRange`  makes sense:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(servicesCollection =>
         {
             var mainServiceCollection = ...;
             servicesCollection.AddRange(mainServiceCollection);
         })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

And here is the extension method which is slightly modified version of yours:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddRange(this IServiceCollection current, IServiceCollection main)
{
    if(current == null)
    {
        throw ArgumentNullException();
    }

    foreach (var serv in main)
    {
        current.Add(serv);
    }

    return current;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping for something like `var newServices = currentServices.CreateChild()` or something like it. I already have the `IServiceCollection` instance and I'm iterating over it to build the new one.

Comment: @dcg Oh, got it, updated my answer. I think extension method is the way to go in that scenario.